# Trying to create two way login form in Laravel - 'Array to string conversion'

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I have normal login form which work great. Now I'm trying to make second simple step when user enter his password and user name and if they are correct to redirect him to new page where he must enter pass phrase in order to continue.

I'm not sure if this is correct what I have make so far. This is my route:

```
Route::get ('/users/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@login', 'before' => 'guest']);
Route::post('/users/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@loginSubmit', 'before' => 'guest']);

// new 
Route::get('/users/auth', ['uses' => 'UsersController@loginAuth', 'before' => 'guest']);
Route::post('/users/auth', ['uses' => 'UsersController@loginSubmitAuth', 'before' => 'auth|csrf']);
```

This is my auth.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(['class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}

    <div class="form-group"> {{ Form::textarea('key', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'key', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }} </div><br/>

    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">Login</button>
    </div>
    <hr />

{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is my controller

```
public function login() {
    return View::make('site.users.login');
}

public function loginSubmit() {
    $validatorRules = array(
        'captcha'  => 'required|captcha',
        'username' => 'required|alpha_dash',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    );

    Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validatorRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    if (!Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password)) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    //$user->last_login = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    //$user->save();
    //Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);
    return Redirect::to('/users/auth');
}
public function loginAuth() {
    return View::make('site.users.auth');
}
public function loginSubmitAuth() {
    $validatorRules = array(
        'key'  => 'required',
        'captcha'  => 'required|captcha'
    );

    Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validatorRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/users/auth')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $user = User::where('key', Input::get('key'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $validator->messages()->add('key', 'Invalid Key.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/auth')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $user->last_login = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
    Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Current error is `'Array to string conversion'`

Any help is appreciated. Thank's

Comment: On which row do you get the error. I suppose Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));

Comment: I've got this in my log and can't see where exactly in the source is this: `'ErrorException' with message 'Array to string conversion' in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php:343`

Comment: I've got this when I click on Login after enter username/password and I've got blank page. Can't reach `auth.blade.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of second parameter in `Form::textarea` you need to pass `null` to make it empty in second parameter and array in third parameter like,

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::textarea('key',null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'key', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
</div><br/>
```

You can refer to [Creating a Textarea Input Field](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/162/creating-a-textarea-input-field)

Comment: Yes, this fixed the blank page error. Now the problem is that when I enter the key it's redirecting me to login page.

Comment: I gave the solution for which you ask the question, but now the error comes because of your logic. I think on pressing `enter`, the validations fails and you are redirecting to login page. For this, if you check it manually then you will definitely find the solution for it.

Comment: You're right. You gave me the solution of initial question and I accept it. Now the error is in comparing logic in the controller. I will try to fix it or will post new question. Thank's!

Comment: No problem, I think you can fix it yourself in a better way. Just see the flow of you routes and functions calls.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try if this fixes your problem:

```
{{ Form::textarea('key', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'key', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
```

It's this way because the value argument comes second and it is mandatory in difference with the third one which is optional